# Adding subitems/children objects from the parent view

Tags: material-design, hierarchy, view

I have a page where users can start a 'timer'. Users can add an Attachment to this timer. So attachments are child objects of a timer.

In the timer page, it's important that there is as little distraction from the timer itself as possible.

This is what I tried myself:

[image]

So I've added a FAB button in the bottom right corner and if you'd click on it, it will show a new view *on top of* the current view with all attachments (pictures) and you'll be able to add attachments.

Some problems with this:

- You can't see how many pictures there are without clicking on the button first
- Users don't know if the button is intended for adding a picture or getting a list of pictures or both

I'm not sure if this is the right thing to do in Material design. Should I create a sublist or table instead? Should I always show the pictures (for example *under* the stop button)?

I couldn't find anything about this type of hierarchy in the material guidelines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The action button you are displaying looks to me like a Take picture action. If you want the attachments not to have much importance you can hide them behind a collapsable panel. Also the add attachment button could be hidden in the panel.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is a really nice example. By making it collapsable it will not distract the user in the initial view but it still allows the user to view all files without having to click on the button.